# Desktop version getting error while moving mouse (cursor.js)

Tags: aframe

I'm taking a version of our VR experience (repo here: https://github.com/EFForg/spot_the_surveillance) and making a purely desktop version for demonstration purposes.

I've added cursor="rayOrigin: mouse" to  and some changed some mouseenter events to click events. Everything is mostly working except that as I mouse over the scene, I repeatedly getting this error: "Uncaught TypeError: t is null", which refers to the following code in cursor.js.

```
// Ignore events further away than active intersection.
if (this.intersectedEl) {
  currentIntersection = this.el.components.raycaster.getIntersection(this.intersectedEl);
  if (currentIntersection.distance <= intersection.distance) { return; }
}
```

How do I resolve this error? It causes a significant lag time in the experience.

Thank you!

Comment: Without a link with simple code to reproduce it will be hard to help. FWIW the html of the link you shared is on an old A-Frame version. Use 1.0.4. More more specific answers I recommend sharing simple code on https://glitch.com/~aframe

Comment: Hi Diego,
The thing is, I'm not sure where in the code the error is being generated because in the console just refers to cursor.js, not my js files. I'll try updating aframe and see if that helps, thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the Mouse Click Example linked from this page was a good place to start: https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/cursor.html#intersection-data

Unfortunately the example is using aframe 0.7.0, so I had to read through the animations documention for 1.0.4 and adapt accordingly: https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/components/animation.html

I also had to update the version of aframe-event-set-component.js I was using.

Between those two sources of information and the version updates, I was able to get things working.